# Can not download files using mobile network but on wifi connection everything is working good

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, wifi

*I am using wifi connection with my app I can download files but when I change the connection to mobile network app is working but not downloading files.*

```
-(NSURLSession *)defaultSession {
if (_defaultSession == nil) {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
    _defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: config delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
}
return _defaultSession;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the following line

```
config.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
```

to

```
config.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
```